# How to change state inside componentDidMount() when recieving a message with websockets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm recieving a websocket message. I want to change the state of my component with this message. When I try to do this, I get an error. How do I solve this?

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.wsConnection.onmessage = function (eventInfo) {

        console.log("Message arrived from websocket: ", eventInfo.data);
        this.setState({team: eventInfo.data});
    };
}
```

My error:

```
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Comment: you changed `this` by creating function using `function` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following code

```
this.wsConnection.onmessage = (eventInfo) => {

    console.log("Message arrived from websocket: ", eventInfo.data);
    this.setState({team: eventInfo.data});
};
```

Comment: This worked! Can you explain the difference between your code and my code? I don't quite understand what's happening.

Comment: There are 2 ways of implementing a function. One is: `function func(var0) {}` and the other one is: `(var0) => {}`. In each type, the scope that the function refers is different. It is about the concept of 'JS closure'. You can get more information on this via this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures